# Simple Boolean And Expression

Tags: excel, boolean

I am trying to express a simple and function, but am making a mistake somewhere.

=AND(C11=Yes,D11=Yes)

I want it to be true if it says yes in both c11 and d11. I'm sure the mistake is simple. Best.

Use the AND function with appropriate arguments in cell H11 to determine if there is a force out at third base. There is a force out at third base if "Runner on 1st" and "Runner on 2nd" are both "Yes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, your cells contain strings.

```
=AND(C11="YES", D11="YES")
```

If, however, the cells contain booleans, it is even simpler

```
=AND(C11, D11)
```